# Arrange a printed statement in numerical order in a function

Tags: python, json, simulation, record

So in a basketball simulation json file, I'm trying to print out the standings in a python function. The file stores everything in objects and arrays ( I think that's what they are called).
The records of each team are stored in a **teams**['seasons'], with each season stored there and then **season**['won'] and **season**['lost'] is where the amount of wins and losses are stored.

This is what I have:

```
import json
filename = 'Basketball.json'
with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as read_file:
    export = json.load(read_file)
teams = export['teams']
players = export['players']

def standings():
    for team in teams:
        for season in team['seasons']:
            if season['season'] == 2021:
                print("{} {} ({}-{})".format(team["region"], team['name'], season['won'], season['lost']))


standings()
```

Output:

```
Los Angeles Lakers (54-28)
Memphis Grizzlies (24-58)
Miami Heat (50-32)
Milwaukee Bucks (52-30)
Minnesota Timberwolves (57-25)
New Orleans Hornets (36-46)
New York Knicks (31-51)
```

The output is printed in alphabetical order of the teams. I want it to be in numerical order with the teams' records with 1st place being at the top and so on. How would i go about to do this?

Answer (score 1):

First, create a `dict` mapping the winnings to the team. Then, sort the `keys` in a list. You can use the [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) builtin function to sort the scores. Pass `reverse=True` so that the the highest winnings come first.

Alternatively, create a list of tuples `(winnings, team_name)` and simply `sort` that.